# Using Access Readers for software access

Tags: authentication, physical-access, identification, rfid

Is it possible to use card access readers for something other than physical access? I've been reading about Wiegand and OSDP protocols and it looks like the hardware is all based on that (with some proprietary aspects for the various manufacturers).

One thing I can't figure out is what comes *back* from these databases. Is it possible to use an RFID badge reader to request identification and authentication for restricting functionality on an embedded or IoT device?

Comment: Such systems already exist - printers which have card readers on are fairly common (most universities I've dealt with have them), and it's quite often the same cards which allow access to rooms or buildings.

Comment: @Matthew good point. So the printers must have some way to slip in to the existing infrastructure. Do you know if there are custom drivers/firmware for these printers depending on the access reader manufacturer?